# Invoke extbase repository in another extension

Tags: extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I am working with 2 extbase extensions products and applications. In products extension I have created TCA's for product and its categories.And in products extension everything is working as intended.

I would like to use the product repository in applications extension . I used the below code and it is working fine, only for corresponding pages. My requirement is that I would like to use the same repository (products repository) with out respecting the pages ids.

```
/**
 * productsRepository
 *
 * @var \VENDOR\Products\Domain\Repository\ProductsRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected ProductsRepository = NULL;
```

I could use  the below code but AFIK it would work only for applications extension

```
$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
```

Can any one help me to find a solution for this ?

PS:I haven't added any model or repository for application extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your product `ProductsRepository` you can override the `initializeObject()` method:

```
public function initializeObject() {
    /** @var $querySettings \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QuerySettingsInterface */
    $querySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\QuerySettingsInterface');
    $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
    $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
}
```

It will affect all queries of the repository, nevermind where are they called from.